# Should I use BFS, DFS for tree traversal or in-order, post -order, pre-order?

Tags: algorithm, graph

This question may be simple for experts  but for a beginner like me it is important. My question is are there any problems involving tree traversals that can be solved by BFS , DFS and not in-order, pre-order etc. In other words, whenever i see a tree problem, should I ONLY think of the 3 tree traversal methods, or also consider BFS,DFS

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pre-order, in-order and post-order traversal are the three different kinds of depth first search that are possible. So it's not a question of whether to use DFS or one of those three. If you are using one of those three traversals, you *are* using DFS.

As for whether there are cases where BFS is preferable over DFS: Yes, there are. For example to find the shortest path between two nodes in an unweighted graph, you can use BFS because the first path found by a BFS happens to be the one with the fewest edges. The same is not true for DFS.

Comment: are there any tree traversals methods similar to BFS?

Comment: it should be noted that there is subtle difference between traversal and search. One goes through all the nodes while the other stops when node is found.

Comment: `For example to find the shortest path between two nodes in an unweighted graph, you can use BFS because the first path found by a BFS happens to be the one with the fewest edges` I believe you meant there are chances that BFS will find the shortest path earlier than DFS but it is not always true . Right ?

Comment: @MSach I mean that if you use a BFS starting at node A and stopping when you find node B in an unweighted graph, then that'll give you the shortest path. If you do the same thing with DFS, you'll get an arbitrary path that may be the shortest only by coincidence and you'd have no way to know whether it's the shortest. The only way to find the shortest path depth-first, would be to perform a full traversal, finding all paths from A to B and then picking the shortest.

Comment: @sepp2k I am just considering the scenario where node `A` is at level 1. Node `B,C,D,E,F` are level 2 where you can come to `E` through `A>B>C>D>E` or `A>F>E` here also we do have to find all path at reaching `E ` ?

Comment: @sepp2k Considering another scenario where node `A` is at level 1. Node `B,C,D,E,F` are level 2 where you can come to `F` through `A>B>C>D>E>F`. Now assume `J` at level 3 and connect back to E. Now `E` can be reached through `A>B>J>E` Is n't it ? So DFS is finding `E` faster than BFS here. Am I missing here anything?

Comment: @MSach Since you're mentioning levels, we're talking about trees, not arbitrary graphs, yes? If so, why do your paths contain multiple nodes on the same level? Also note that in a tree there's only one path from one node to another anyway, so finding the shortest path becomes equivalent to just finding any path. Also, can you please clarify which nodes are connected to which other nodes in your examples?

Comment: Connection is like this `A>B>C>D>E<F<A` in first example. In second example extra connection  is   `A>B>J>E`

Comment: @MSach If `A` has edges to `B` and `F`, `B` has an edge to `C`, `C` to `D`, `D` to `E` and `F` to `E`, then BFS would visit `A, B, F, C, E` and thus find the path `A->F->E` before it even visits `D`. DFS on the other hand would visit `A, B, C, D, E` and thus find the longer path first.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious example where DFS doesn't work and you *have* to use BFS is an infinitely (or at least arbitrarily) high tree.